# Understanding sendmail -bt in conjunction with aliases

Tags: email, redhat, sendmail

I'm familiar with exim and the behaviour of exim -bt in indicating how a message will be routed. I'm trying to set up a trivial sendmail configuration to route root mail on a local system to my company email address.

```
# tail /etc/aliases

# Person who should get root's mail
root:       pjc50@example.com
```

Having run `newaliases`, this currently **works properly**. But I can't understand **how** to verify that locally with -bt.

```
# sendmail -bt
ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
Enter <ruleset> <address>
> /try smtp root
Trying envelope recipient address root for mailer smtp
canonify           input: root
Canonify2          input: root
Canonify2        returns: root
canonify         returns: root
2                  input: root
2                returns: root
EnvToSMTP          input: root
PseudoToReal       input: root
PseudoToReal     returns: root
MasqSMTP           input: root
MasqSMTP         returns: root < @ *LOCAL* >
EnvToSMTP        returns: root < @ olympus . domain . >
final              input: root < @ olympus . domain . >
final            returns: root @ olympus . domain
Rcode = 0, addr = root@olympus.domain
> 3 root
canonify           input: root
Canonify2          input: root
Canonify2        returns: root
canonify         returns: root
> /try local root
Trying envelope recipient address root for mailer local
canonify           input: root
Canonify2          input: root
Canonify2        returns: root
canonify         returns: root
2                  input: root
2                returns: root
EnvToL             input: root
EnvToL           returns: root
final              input: root
final            returns: root
Rcode = 0, addr = root
>
```

What should I be entering that starts with `root` and outputs `pjc50@example.com`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `sendmail -bv root`.
It should show how where sendmail is going to deliver messages for given recipient.

`man sendmail` :

> ```
>    -bv    Verify  names only - do not try to collect or deliver a message.
>           Verify mode is normally used for  validating  users  or  mailing
>           lists.
> ```

---

If you want to see also processing by internal rulesets then add `-d21.12` debugging switch to `-bv`.